# AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers stops background music the first time when audio is player, only once

Tags: ios, flutter, avaudioplayer

My app plays sounds such as timers. It should not pause or duck any background music. I use the `audio_sessions` package with config for it:

```
AudioSession.instance.then((session) async {
  await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
    avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.ambient,
    avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers,
    avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode,
    avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy: AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
    avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
    // ANDROID
    androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
      contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.sonification,
      flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
      usage: AndroidAudioUsage.game,
    ),
    androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
    androidWillPauseWhenDucked: false,
  ));

  await session.setActive(true);

  // Init audio players...
});
```

For some reason, my app pauses the background music once when I play the first audio. If I continue the music, go back in my app, and play other sounds, it no longer pauses the music.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?